# Undefined symbol "_clone" on OS X

Tags: c, macos, x86-64, linker-errors

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define _GNU_SOURCE

void *stack_memory() 
{
    const int stackSize = 65536;
    void* stack = (void*)malloc(stackSize);
    if (stack == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", "Cannot allocate memory \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return stack;
}

int jail(void *args) 
{
    printf("Hello !! - child \n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", "Hello, world! - parent");
    clone(jail, stack_memory(), SIGCHLD, 0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Error:**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_clone", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in docker-4f3ae8.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You need to add library `glibc` to your linker settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux doesn't prefix symbols with a leading `_` so you're not using Linux.

But the `clone(2)` system call is Linux-specific, according to [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html#CONFORMING_TO).

> clone() is Linux-specific and should not be used in programs intended
>          to be portable.

---

Probably you're using OS X or something.  And you're compiling as C, so calling an un-declared function isn't a compile-time error (just a big warning).  This is why it's a linker error instead of a compile-time error (and you ignored compiler warnings.)

And BTW, `#define _GNU_SOURCE` *after* including header files is pointless.  You have to define feature-request macros *before* including headers to get them to define prototypes for GNU-only functions in cases where that's not already the default.

Comment: Yes, I use OS X